# convert sentences in a column to list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My current dataframe looks like this

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | i like apple |
| Second | alex is friends with jack |

I am expecting

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | [i, like, apple] |
| Second | [alex, is, friends, with, jack] |

How can I accomplish this efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [standard str operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) on the column:

```py
df['Another header'] = df['Another header'].str.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['Another header'] = df['Another header'].str.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` with a `lambda` function

```py
df['Another header'] = list(map(lambda x: x.split(' '), df['Another header']))
```

Comment: what is the advantage of this vs optimised in built functions?

Comment: @Matt I have to test it against the other options by using a large dataframe example